# ¿Cómo se puede hacer un salto de linea con font.render en pygame?

Tags: python, windows, pygame

Este es mi código:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

fondo = (0, 0, 0)
texto = (255, 0, 0)


X = 600
Y = 600

display_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((X, Y))
pygame.display.set_caption('Game Over')
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Master of break', 40)
text = font.render('Game Over \n By Canseco', True, texto)
textRect = text.get_rect()
textRect.center = (X // 2, Y // 2)


while True:
    display_surface.fill(fondo)
    display_surface.blit(text, textRect)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        pygame.display.update()
```

Necesito separar el "Game Over" del "By Canseco". Solo es para un proyecto personal (un juego), como podrán ver soy principiante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la propia documentación de [`pygame.font.Font.render`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render):

> The text can only be a single line: newline characters are not
> rendered.

---

Por lo que el texto solo pude estar compuesto por una sola linea, dado que los caracteres de nueva linea no son renderizados.

En tu caso, la opción mas simple es generar dos surfaces, una por cada linea de texto y mostrarlas en la posición apropiada según el interlineado que quieras, por ejemplo:

```
import pygame


X = 600
Y = 600
BACKGROUND_COLOR = (0, 0, 0)
TEXT_COLOR = (255, 0, 0)
TEXT_SPACING = 10

pygame.init()

display_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((X, Y))
pygame.display.set_caption('Game Over')

font_title = pygame.font.SysFont('Master of break', 40)
font_subtitle = pygame.font.SysFont('Master of break', 30)

text_line_1 = font_title.render('Game Over', True, TEXT_COLOR)
text_line_2 = font_subtitle.render('By Canseco', True, TEXT_COLOR)
text_line_1_rect = text_line_1.get_rect()
text_line_2_rect = text_line_2.get_rect()

text_height = text_line_1_rect.height + text_line_2_rect.height + TEXT_SPACING

text_line_1_rect.center = (
    X // 2,
    Y // 2 - (text_height // 2 - text_line_1_rect.height // 2)
    )
text_line_2_rect.center = (
    X // 2,
    Y // 2 + (text_height // 2 - text_line_2_rect.height // 2)
    )

while True:
    display_surface.fill(BACKGROUND_COLOR)
    display_surface.blit(text_line_1, text_line_1_rect)
    display_surface.blit(text_line_2, text_line_2_rect)
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        pygame.display.update()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Disculpa la ignoracia, pero mi compilador se traba al intentar ejecutar ese codigo, ademas de que no muestra letras, solo pantalla negra

Comment: Es el unico problema

Comment: Hola @Alberto, es mi culpa, faltaba el mainloop para que el ejemplo fuera totalmente reproducible, al pegar y formatear el código de la respuesta por alguna razón esa parte se perdió... He editado la respuesta, ahora todo debería funcionar.

Comment: ok, muchas gracias